# GestureDetector / Inkwell inside Overlay misaligned on iPhones that have a bottom notch

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a full screen Overlay that hosts a Minimize / Maximize button, and this button works perfectly on Android and iOS phones that don't have a bottom notch.

Examples of working devices:

- Pixel 3 (emulator)
- iPhone 8 (emulator)

Examples of problematic devices:

- iPhone 11

When the Overlay is "maximized", the hit detection is spot on. When "minimized", the hit detection is offset downwards. The "MinMax" FlatButton (see below) needs to be tapped at a very specific spot under the text of the button.

Futhermore, the missed hit detection doesn't offset gradually as the size of the Overlay gets smaller. You can see this by increasing the minimized size from 0.08. Any change in size at all causes the hit detection to miss at the same spot.

The following minimal repro demonstrates the issue:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isMinimized = false;
  StreamController<bool> _isMinimimizedController = StreamController<bool>();
  OverlayEntry _activeOverlay;

  Widget _buildOverlay() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          top: !_isMinimized,
          bottom: _isMinimized,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildOverlayHeader(),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOverlayHeader() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('MinMax'),
              onPressed: () {
                _isMinimized = !_isMinimized;
                _isMinimimizedController.sink.add(_isMinimized);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openOverlay() {
    if (_activeOverlay != null || context == null) {
      return;
    }

    _activeOverlay = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return StreamBuilder<bool>(
          stream: _isMinimimizedController.stream,
          initialData: false,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

            var height = mediaQuery.size.height;
            var top = 0.0;

            if (_isMinimized) {
              height = height * 0.08;
              top = mediaQuery.size.height - height;
            }

            return AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
              width: mediaQuery.size.width,
              height: mediaQuery.size.height,
              top: top,
              left: 0,
              // Child navigator is necessary to show modals on top of the overlay
              child: Navigator(onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                var builder = (BuildContext context) => _buildOverlay();
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (builder), settings: settings);
              }),
            );
          });
    });

    Overlay.of(context).insert(_activeOverlay);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: openOverlay,
        tooltip: 'Open',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is causing the hit detection miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with how I was toggling the SafeArea's top and bottom properties here:

```
      body: SafeArea(
          top: !_isMinimized,
          bottom: _isMinimized,
```

The solution was to remove the "top" and "bottom" lines so that they always defaults to true. I then calculate the minimized height of the header manually.